# Django filter queryset to find lowest price of product or preferred merchant price if prices are the same

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-filter

I have the following in `models.py`:

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    priority = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class MerchantWine(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey("Merchant")
    wine_vintage = models.ForeignKey("WineVintage")
    price = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    minimum_purchase_unit = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**Question**: In my queryset I'm trying to restrict the MerchantWine objects to

A. the lowest price version where there are duplicate WineVintages and 
 B. if prices are the same then Id like to select the price corresponding to the Merchant with the lowest priority.

In my `views.py` I tried the following:

```
        def get_queryset(self):
            #A Restrict MerchantWines to lowest price version(s) of same wine_vintage
            minimum_prices = MerchantWine.objects.values('wine_vintage').annotate(lowest_price=Min('price'))
            results_list = MerchantWine.objects.filter(price__in=minimum_prices.values('lowest_price'))
            #B Restrict MerchantWines to preferred merchant of same wine_vintage and price
            preferred_merchants = results_list.values('wine_vintage').annotate(lowest_priority=Min('merchant__priority'))
            results_list = results_list.filter(merchant__priority__in=preferred_merchants.values('lowest_priority')) # NOT WORKING ON PROD: Chardonnay
            return results_list
```

It seems that A.) is working but B.) does not always work.

Can anyone help? 
Many thanks in advance.